# Pinching (zoom) gesture not scaling correctly

Tags: ios, xcode

Im trying to figure out why my scaling is acting very strange on my OpenGL camera.
Its purpose is it zoom in and out, but its scaling very random.

Heres my code:

```
- (void)pinchDetected:(UIPinchGestureRecognizer *)pinchRecognizer
{
    NSLog (@"%@", @"Pinching");

    if (pinchRecognizer.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateBegan ||
               pinchRecognizer.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateChanged ||
               pinchRecognizer.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded) {
        currentScale = pinchRecognizer.scale;
    }

    if(lastScale < currentScale) {
       _camera.z += currentScale * 0.01f;
       lastScale = currentScale;
    } 

    if (lastScale > currentScale) 
    {
       _camera.z -= currentScale * 0.01f;
       lastScale = currentScale;
    }

}
```

Comment: It changes from time to time, so it basically doesnt scale with a continuous factor.. If that makes sense?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have something that is multiplicative and you want to make it additive, you need to take a log:

```
- (void)pinchDetected:(UIPinchGestureRecognizer *)pinchRecognizer
{
    if ((gesture.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateBegan) ||
        (gesture.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateChanged) ||
        (gesture.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded)) {
        _camera.z += log(gesture.scale); // you'll probably want to multiply this by some constant
        gesture.scale = 1.0;
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you give a more complete example? Cause this does not work correctly.

Comment: This is a complete example. As I said in my comment, the only thing you'd need to do is to multiply the log by a constant, e.g. `_camera.z += someConstant * log(gesture.scale);` where someConstant is some number.

Comment: i understand that clearly, but when pinching in and out it does not occur so smooth, and it does not always react on inverted pinching. Is there something wrong with the gesture state?